# How to fetch Response Code of http post request using curl invoked from a batch script?

Tags: http, batch-file, curl, return-value, httpresponse

I am working on providing support for sending http post requests from one of our tools. The tool basically executes a job via http requests.

The way this is achieved is the tool makes a call to RunScript.bat with a number of arguments. The script parses these args and makes a curl post request after validation. The Post request is handled by our internal Java Service.

What I want is my batch file should be able to fetch the Response Code (200/409 etc.) of the post request and based on this, the script should return 1 or 0 as exit value back to the tool.
The tool then marks the job pass/fail based on the return value.

**Tool: Parses the returned value**

RunScript.bat arg1 arg2 arg3

**RunScript.bat**

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
ECHO %DATE% %TIME% Calling %0 with %*
SET "SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0"
ECHO Script Dir %SCRIPT_DIR%
SET cmd=%1
SET val2=%2
SET val3=%3

%SCRIPT_DIR%\curl -v -X POST http://localhost:9500/%cmd%/%val2%/%val3%
```

Is it possible to fetch the Response Code of the curl request in the batch script and then return 1/0 based on the Response Code ?

Comment: Why are you setting variables unnecessarily? `"%~dp0curl.exe" -v -X POST "http://localhost:9500/%~1/%~2/%~3"`. If you still wanted them set, then you'll need to use them properly, `"%SCRIPT_DIR%curl.exe" -v -X POST "http://localhost:9500/%cmd%/%val2%/%val3%"`. I would also suggest that you change the variable name from `cmd` as it may confuse future readers of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing we need is to get `curl` to output the HTTP status. For this I used [pvandenberk's answer](https://superuser.com/a/442395/347295) to [Getting curl to output HTTP status code?](https://superuser.com/q/272265/347295). Next, we have to get that output into an environment variable so we can test it. For this we use the `for /f %%a in ( 'command-to-execute' ) do ...` form of the `for` command (see `for /?` for more details).

Incorporating these (and some other minor tweaks), something like the following should help:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
ECHO %DATE% %TIME% Calling %0 with %*
SET "SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0"
ECHO Script Dir %SCRIPT_DIR%
SET "cmd=%1"
SET "val2=%2"
SET "val3=%3"
SET "URL=http://localhost:9500/%cmd%/%val2%/%val3%"

SET HTTP=
for /f %%a in ( '"%SCRIPT_DIR%\curl" -s -o nul -v -X POST -w "%%{http_code}" "%URL%"' ) do set HTTP=%%a

if "%HTTP%" == "200" (
    exit /b 0
) else (
    exit /b 1
)
```

**Notes:**

- I've assumed `cmd`, `val2` and `val3` in your original URL were meant to be replaced with the contents of the earlier environment variables, so have changed them to `%cmd%` etc. when building `URL`.
- In the `for` statement, the whole of the command to be executed is enclosed in single-quotes (`'.....'`).
- I've wrapped the invocation of curl in double-quotes (`"%SCRIPT_DIR%\curl"`): this should allow it to work even if the script-directory were to contain spaces.
- I've added `-s` (silent) and `-o nul` (where to send the full response) to curl's command-line. This will help to ensure any output returned from the `POST` request does not interfere with the HTTP status code. If you need to see this output, use `-o filename` and `TYPE` the file before making the test on `HTTP`.
- The percent-sign in `-w "%%{http_code}"` needs to be doubled because it has special meaning to the shell.
- The output of `-v` (verbose) is sent to `stderr` so shouldn't interfere with capturing the HTTP response code.

---

### Update

To get both the HTTP response code, and still see the output from the curl command itself you could try replacing the `for /f ...` line above with the one below:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( '"%SCRIPT_DIR%\curl" -v -X POST -w "%%{http_code}" "%URL%"' ) do set "HTTP=%%a" && echo %%a
```

- The `"delims="` means that the lines of output from curl will not be split into separate tokens so `%%a` will hold the whole of each line.
- I've removed the `-s` and `-o nul` options, so the original output from curl will still be generated.
- The `set "HTTP=%%a"` command has had double-quotes added to prevent trailing spaces being added to the environment variable. Because the response code (e.g. 404) is the last line emitted by curl, the final value of `HTTP` will still be what we want.
- The `echo %%a` will replay all lines generated by curl.

Comment: Thanks user name:@TripeHound for the answer.
It does the trick and works well.

In my case, there is an additional thing required as well.
The Web Service returns back a String with reason in case of ERROR at the server side while processing Post Request.
Now, I am also interested to print the returned String as well.

Earlier, when I was simply invoking %SCRIPT_DIR%\cur -v -X POST %URL%, 
it used to print the returned String.

But, with the modified method you suggested, it doesn't do that anymore.
Any suggestions for that ?
-o filename ?

Comment: No, you haven't missed anything as per the question. Your answer is perfect.
It's just that with the way you suggested, it doesn't print the returned ERROR reason from server which used to print earlier.
Probably because -o nul.

My script actually needs 2 things: ResponseCode to signal 0/1 and Error reason returned back by web service.

Comment: That's probably the `-o nul` I mentioned in the notes. Try initially changing it to `-o response.txt` and then adding `type response.txt` after the call to curl. If that works, two things you might need to do is (a) delete the file if it exists before the call (in case an old version is still around) and (b) depending on whether multiple copies of the script can be run at the same time, using a unique name so they don't overwrite each other. You could also try removing the `-s`.

Comment: Thanks @TripeHound.
I tried with -o resp.txt and type resp.txt.
This works and does the intended task.

But, you are right that multiple copies of the script will be running at the same time and that will need some work.
But, thanks a lot.

Comment: @PeXXeR I've made an update which should hopefully get you your output without using a holding file.

Comment: Thank you very much @TripeHound.
Really appreciate your response.
Yeah, the Updated way works the way I wanted :)

Cheers.