# Is it possible for a batch script to 'catch' a powershell error?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

This is my batch code and it's works find as long as the url being checked is a valid url, but gets the following error if you put in an invalid url
**URL Status=
( was unexpected at this time.**

```
@Echo Off
Set CheckUrl=`Powershell.exe -nologo -NoProfile -command "(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://exceedtstab.infarmbureau.com/Exceed).StatusCode"`
For /f "usebackqdelims=" %%A in (
    %CheckUrl%
) Do Set UrlStatus=%%A
Echo URL Status=%UrlStatus%
IF %UrlStatus% == 200 ( 
    Echo URL Connected to internet
    goto :eof
) else (
    Echo URL Not connected to internet
)
```

Comment: It sounds like the solution to this problem is to just instruct whoever maintains the script _not_ to add an invalid url...

Comment: Build it into your PowerShell snippet. `try { (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://exceedtstab.infarmbureau.com/Exceed).StatusCode } catch { "100" }`

Comment: DUH!....Thanks...that worked! Make it an answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: [How to fetch Response Code of http post request using curl invoked from a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59386902/how-to-)    fetch-response-code-of-http-post-request-using-curl-invoked-from-a-batch

So for your case it should be someting like this:

```
@echo off
SET URL="http://exceedtstab.infarmbureau.com/Exceed"
SET HTTP=
for /f %%a in ( 'curl -i -w "%%{http_code}" "%URL%"' ) do set HTTP=%%a

if "%HTTP%" == "200" (
    echo HTTP Code is: 200
    exit /b 0
) else (
    echo HTTP Code is: %HTTP%
    exit /b 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can test the "UrlStatus" variable with double quotes around it, just in case it's blank; then you won't get that error message, "( was unexpected at this time."

```
IF "%UrlStatus%" == "200" (
```